# Typescript share property types

Tags: typescript

In typescript I have this interface.

```
export interface FlexProps {
  justifyContent:
  | "initial"
  | "center"
  | "flex-start"
  | "flex-end"
  | "space-between"
  | "space-around";

  alignItems:
  | "initial"
  | "center"
  | "stretch"
  | "flex-start"
  | "flex-end"
  | "baseline";
}
```

Is there a way I can transform this into?

```
    const shared: "initial" | "center" | "flex-start" | "flex-end"

    export interface FlexProps {
      justifyContent: shared | "space-between" | "space-around";
      alignItems: shared | "stretch" | "baseline";
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by transform, you can write it just the way you have in your second example, should work and be equivalent to your original code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have made a typo when declaring your shared types. You have used `const` but it should be `type`:

```
-  const shared: "initial" | "center" | "flex-start" | "flex-end"
+  type shared = "initial" | "center" | "flex-start" | "flex-end";

   export interface FlexProps {
     justifyContent: shared | "space-between" | "space-around";
     alignItems: shared | "stretch" | "baseline";
   }
```

Here is a [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAzgFgQwE4QCZQLxQEQEsB2uwuCANtlAD44DGE+wESF12AZqRAB4C0MwyYCxwduPeqmwBuAFAyCjJGwR0oAMU5cACkgD2YGFADeMqGagArAK79cbEAGFdDesABcsRCnSsYYFRA8AEYQwADuEPTC2H4BPMi6VviSsuZQZLgA5vgAkowAtjAe8MhoVDj8KMA0cNFBCDAQpAQQ0jIAvkA):

```
type shared = "initial" | "center" | "flex-start" | "flex-end";

interface FlexProps {
    justifyContent: shared | "space-between" | "space-around";
    alignItems: shared | "stretch" | "baseline";
}
```